# Can a neutrinos mass oscillate in a similar way to its flavour?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

So I've been reading up on neutrino oscillations and I think I'm making some progress in understanding it, but I'm still a long way off. As I understand it, you can 'classify' neutrinos in two ways; by their mass, or their flavour. Given the mass of a neutrino, you cannot say which flavour it is - ie. it is a superposition of the three. Alternatively, given the flavour, you cannot say for certain its mass (I think :/ ). Does this mean that the neutrino will oscillate between masses? If so, I would assume the three masses are discrete and it is the probability that oscillates?

If anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated, I haven't really done much QM so when I read things like 'the mass and flavour eigenstates are unequal' I get a little confused, is this saying what I have said above or am I being oversimplistic?

Comment: See figure.4 and read the 2 flavor case from [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0001264.pdf).

Comment: Search the Google for mass varying neutrino models.

Comment: ***No***, a mass-eigenstate  will not oscillate to another mass eigenstate in mid flight! However, it is almost always propagating in tandem with the other two mass eigenstates, with which it was produced (in a flavor "eigenstate"), and it is impossible to isolate it from those, let alone detect it!